# swift query search for appended array

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have found names and appended them to `var nameArray = [String]()` , but how to make another query which is for nameArray ?

```
    query.whereKey("receiver", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in


        if error == nil {


            for object in objects! {

                self.nameArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
            }
```

now how can i make another query to search for names in nameArray ? like this:

```
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.nameArray as! String)
```

i'm getting error can't convert [String] to 'String' .. how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you have `as! String` ?

Comment: I don't know if i type as String, i'm getting error, could you help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate error is that you are trying to tell the compiler to convert an array of string to a string, and it knows that isn't possible:

```
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.nameArray as! String)
```

should be

```
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.nameArray)
```

But, it's also likely that you should be using a different criteria to find matches:

```
query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.nameArray)
```